# /testforblock command not recognizing items in the chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In my custom map there is a point where the items in the chest have to be tested, so I wrote this command:

```
/testforblock -17 105 198 minecraft:chest 5 {Items:[{id:1,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:1,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:1,Slot:14,Count:4}]}
```

To a command block (and kept it in a loop of 1/2 of a second) but it gives the following error:

> The block at -17,105,198 did not have the required NBT keys.

But there is a chest there 100% (if thats the case). I will leave a screenshot of the chests so to determine if there is any placement issue. Layout of my chest:

[image: description]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When testing for pre-existing NBT data, you must specify all data as it was stored. This includes proper string values for item IDs (you should **not** be using numerical IDs to begin with) as well as correct datatype declaration for all data.

The `id` tag stores a string, being the name ID of the item (including the namespace, defaulting to "minecraft"). Both the `Slot` and `Count` tags are stored as bytes, so you append the whole numerical value with a "b".

Fixed command:

```
/testforblock -17 105 198 minecraft:chest 5 {Items:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:0b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:1b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:2b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:3b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:4b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:5b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:6b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:7b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:8b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:9b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:10b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:11b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:12b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:13b,Count:64b},{id:"minecraft:stone",Slot:14b,Count:4b}]}
```

Comment: Thx @Skylinerw it really helped me